# In a principal $G$-bundle $\pi: P \to M$ there is a right action on $P$ such that $M \cong P/G$

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Suppose we have a principal $G$-bundle $\pi: P \to M$. The definition of principal bundle is: a fiber bundle with a $G$-structure, fiber $G$ and action on fiber given by left multiplication. We can define a right action on $P$ and prove that this is free and proper. So  $P/G$ is a manifold. I want to prove that $P/G \cong M$. I can define the bijection $[x] \to \pi(x)$, but I don't how to prove that it is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the action being free and proper, you have a smooth structure on $P/G$ such that the standard projection $p:P\to P/G$ is a submersion.

With $p$ being a surjective submersion, you have the property that a function $f:P/G\to M$ is smooth if and only if $f\circ p$ is smooth. If $f$ is given by $f([x])=\pi(x)$, then $f\circ p=\pi$, which is smooth.

Furthermore, $\pi$ is also a surjective submersion (if this is not clear to you, you can check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136987/projection-of-fiber-bundle-is-a-submersion)), so you can apply the same argument for the inverse.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find the proof of the fact that $f$ is smooth if and only if $fp$ is smooth?

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119732/what-is-the-characteristic-property-of-surjective-submersions) question is about that property and mentions that it is stated in Jack Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Maybe you can find a proof there.

Comment: If you don't, then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320102/local-submersion-theorem-differential-topology-of-guillemin-and-pollack) question discusses the fact that, given a submersion, you can always find coordinates such that its local representation is the canonical submersion (also known as the [submersion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)#Local_normal_form)). That local representation should be enough to prove the result.